# Disadvantages/Problems with using Apache Beam instead of using Spark directly?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink, apache-beam

I need to start a new project, and I do not know if Spark or Flink would be better. Currently, the project needs micro-batching but later it could require stream-event-handling as well.

Suppose Spark would be best, is there any disadvantage to using Beam instead and selecting Spark/Flink as the runner/engine?

Will Beam add any overhead or lack certain API/functions available in Spark/Flink?

Comment: This is a really good question. Could you ask in user@beam.apache.org as Beam developers who develop Spark and Flink runners are there. They have expertise to answer "Will Beam add any overhead or lack certain API/functions available in Spark/Flink?".

Comment: I've just sent it to that mailing list. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer a part of your question:

First of all, Beam defines API to program for data processing. To adopt it, you have to first understand its programming model and make sure its model will fit your need.

Assuming you have fairly understood what Beam could help you, and you are planning to select Spark as the execution runner, you can check runner capability matrix[1] for Beam API support on Spark.

Regarding to overhead of running Beam over Spark. You might need to ask in user@beam.apache.org or dev@beam.apache.org. Runner developers could have better answers on it.

[1] https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/capability-matrix/